# Technical or lie? Internal job posting requirements

Tags: applications

I was told verbally of a job posting before it was ever typed up. The applications weren’t given to be filled out until it was actually posted. When filling it out I ran across the question “how did you hear of this position “.. I froze. I lied and said internal job posting because I didn’t know if putting “my supervisor told me “ was a good answer or not. Now regardless of what would’ve sounded better I regret lying and feel undeserving of my position. I’ve held d this position for over a year and feel convicted for that minor lie. Some say it wasn’t a lie and some say it was but no big deal. I know that answer wasn’t why I was given the position but still.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I follow you. You applied before the requirement went out?

Comment: So did you fill it out *after* it became an internal job posting or did you have any advantages the other candidates did not have by filling it out early?

Comment: I filled the application out AFTER it was officially a posting. I was told of the position however verbally before the official physical  listing. Another girl I knew had heard of the position verbally before it was posted also but didn’t get the position. We were both considered and told verbally by the same person but after our interview only I got the position based off of my interview .

Comment: Could you spell out what it is you actually think you've done wrong? It sounds like it was a level playing field - even being told early doesn't give you an advantage unless it was on a first come first served (interviewed) basis and no one else was considered.

Comment: Lol. I over think. I guess I feel like a liar since I didn’t specifically state where I had heard of the position. I just out “internal job posting “. I try too hard to be overly honest then feel undeserving afterward

Comment: There are many different kinds of lies. We all "lie", in one way or another, frequently. A lie can be a subtle as omitting an unnecessary detail that was unprompted, or, it can be a deliberate attempt to deceive someone for the purpose of gaining advantage at their expense. I find it disturbing that you you are judging yourself so harshly that you believe you don't deserve your position, it's hard to imagine. It also makes me wonder how harshly you would judge others for transgressions so minor that most people would forget about them before the day is over.

Comment: Just say, "I was invited to apply by my supervisor."  No lie.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. I guess I wanted some reassurance that what I did wasn’t a lie. Seems it still was and I knew that. Although the lie had no bearing on me getting the position. I just try to be 100 percent honest and even though it’s something small it eats me up that I was too cowardly and went against my conscience and didn’t just put the right answer

Comment: I think it was good to give a vague answer, it could have been a serious problem for the person filling you in early if you wrote that down.

Answer (score 14):

I'd say you're overthinking this - it's unlikely to ever come up again or to have had any real bearing on the recruitment process. Most likely the question was simply there for tracking how effective their means of communicating the existence of such positions are.

Carry on and enjoy your new position.

Comment: Yes I definitely overthink. Then I feel guilty and disqualify myself from certain things. I just feel like a liar for not specifying where I heard of the position.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of asking how you found out about the job posting is often to work out what their most lucrative way of job advertisement is, and use this to help when advertising future job posts.

Whatever you put in that box would not have influenced their decision to give you the job. Some won't have even read what was in that box. You didn't have any advantages over anyone else, you waited until the job was open, and applied. They hired you based on your application and proven skills, not how you found out about the job.

Comment: Thank you. I just have anxiety and feel guilty when I’m not 100 percent honest. Smh. It’s debilitating.

Comment: @MsOverThinker I deal with the same thing, imposter syndrome is also pretty normal!

Answer (score 1):

as your name suggests I feel that you are over thinking this a bit. 
if you didn't fill out the application till after the job was posted publicly then you had no advantage over external candidates and like you said you beat another interal candidate because you had a better interview and they would have had the same (if any) advantages as you. your supervisor wouldn't have told you about the job if they didn't think you were good enough and you also wouldn't have got the job. so relax

Comment: Thank you. I hate feeling like a liar because technically I did lie  just makes me feel guilty and undeserving of the position for that minor statement of saying internal listing instead of from my supervisor .

Comment: how I see it is, you were unsure how to answer a question so decided to give a vague answer. also in the grand sceme of things you could have put "found advert stapled to the side of a stray dog" and you still would have got an interview, your manager told you about the job, they probably told the hiring manager about you.

Answer (score -1):

your boss is in the company so it's internal.

It just means you got the lead inside your company.  Your boss is inside the company, he told you about it so the lead was internal.

Comment: this reads more like a comment than an answer, mind enhancing it?

Comment: I was just saying I felt bad for my answer I left on the application instead of being 100% forth coming.